# PHP preparing queries not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to prepare a query before sending it to the database but it isn't taking anything out of the database. It tells me that the user/pass combo is incorrect. (when it is correct) which must mean that it has 0 rows in coming from the database. Can anybody possibly tell me how to fix this?

```
/* Create a prepared statement */
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND userpass = ?");

        /* Bind parameters
        s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $userpass);

        /* Execute it */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* Bind results */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $userpass);

        /* Fetch the value */
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 


        /* $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users 
            WHERE username = '$username' AND userpass = '$userpass'"); */


        if(!$stmt)  
        {  
            //something went wrong, display the error  
            echo '<ul class="ulstylecenter">
            <li>Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.</li>
            <li>If you are not redirected in 5 seconds please <a href="/home.php">click here</a>.</li>
            </ul>';  
            header('Refresh: 5;url=/home.php');
            //echo mysqli_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            //the query was successfully executed, there are 2 possibilities 
            //1. the query returned data, the user can be signed in 
            //2. the query returned an empty result set, the credentials were wrong 
            if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt) == 0) 
            { 
                echo '<ul class="ulstylecenter">
                <li>You have supplied a wrong user/password combination. Please try again.</li></ul>';
                echo '<form method="post" action="">  
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <th><label for="username" class="signinlabel">Username:</label></th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" value="';
                        if(isset($username)){ echo $username; }
                        echo '" class="signininput"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>  
                        <th><label for="userpass" class="signinlabel">Password:</label></th>
                        <td><input type="password" name="userpass" class="signininput"></td>
                        </tr> 
                        </table>
                        <ul class="forgotsignin"><li><a href="#">Forgot your username or password?</a></li></ul>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="signinbutton" id="signinbuttonid">  
                </form>';
            } 
            else 
            { 
            $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true; 

                //we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) 
                { 
                    $_SESSION['user_id']   = $row['user_id']; 
                    $_SESSION['username']  = $row['username']; 
                    $_SESSION['useremail'] = $row['useremail']; 
                    $_SESSION['userdate'] = $row['userdate'];
                } 
                echo '<ul class="ulstylecenter">
                    <li>Succesfully logged in.</li>
                    <li>If you are not redirected in 5 seconds please <a href="/home.php">click here</a>.
                    </li></ul>'; 
                header('Refresh: 5;url=/home.php');
            }
```

Comment: You should start with adding error handling to your database calls.

Comment: Is your passwords stored in plain text or a hash of some sort?

Comment: "It tells me that" - please provide the error REPORTED not your interpretation. Also trim down your code to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of flaws in your code. Only some of them:

1. You need to add to `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` params variables that will represent all columns of your table `users`. For example if you have table fields:

   ```
   id    username    password    email    date
   ```

   your `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` call should look like this:

   ```
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $userpass, $email, $date);
   ```

   because query contains `SELECT *`.
2. Do not check `if (!$stmt)` after `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);`.
3. If you already have `$username` and `$userpass` values doesn't make sense to retrieve them from database again...

It's highly recommended to read carefully whole [mysqli documendation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

I think your code should look like this (if you prefer on procedural mysqli style):

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT user_id, useremail, userdate FROM users WHERE username = ? AND userpass = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $userpass);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

if (mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt)) {
    //something went wrong, display the error
    echo '<ul class="ulstylecenter">
            <li>Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.</li>
            <li>If you are not redirected in 5 seconds please <a href="/home.php">click here</a>.</li>
            </ul>';
    header('Refresh: 5;url=/home.php');
    //echo mysqli_stmt_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
} elseif (0 === mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)) {
    //the query was successfully executed, there are 2 possibilities
    //1. the query returned data, the user can be signed in
    //2. the query returned an empty result set, the credentials were wrong

    echo '<ul class="ulstylecenter">
            <li>You have supplied a wrong user/password combination. Please try again.</li></ul>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th><label for="username" class="signinlabel">Username:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" value="';
    if (isset($username)) {
        echo $username;
    }
    echo '" class="signininput"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <th><label for="userpass" class="signinlabel">Password:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="password" name="userpass" class="signininput"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <ul class="forgotsignin"><li><a href="#">Forgot your username or password?</a></li></ul>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="signinbutton" id="signinbuttonid">
            </form>';
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;

    //we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $useremail, $userdate);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['useremail'] = $useremail;
    $_SESSION['userdate'] = $userdate;

    echo '<ul class="ulstylecenter">
                <li>Succesfully logged in.</li>
                <li>If you are not redirected in 5 seconds please <a href="/home.php">click here</a>.
                </li></ul>';
    header('Refresh: 5;url=/home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your variables with var_dump() then try to set variables $username and $userpass *after* this line :

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $userpass);
```